# Migrated Customers not able to complete the purchased

Tags: magento2.3, customer, migration

Before is started in this company they migrated a lot of customers from Magento 1.9 to Magento 2.3.

The issue we are seeing with customers that is from Magento 2 is when they go to checkout they receive this error message ("The shipping information was unable to be saved. Verify the input data and try again.
Where it shows "Payment Method" it is blank and a spinning loading wheel.
But the strange thing is if i click on the "add new address" button and type in the same iformation and hit save everything seams to work again. Error message gone and payment method loads perfectly...

Edit: I found this error in Magento exception log:
[2020-09-14 20:31:06] main.CRITICAL: Invalid customer address id 1667 {"exception":"[object] (Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException(code: 0): Invalid customer address id 1667 at /chroot/home/xxxxx/rodin.etailhandel.no/html/vendor/magento/module-quote/Model/QuoteAddressValidator.php:79)"} []

Anyone have any ideas what can cause this?

Comment: Try this https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/23618

Comment: Thanks for this, will have a look and see if this can be fixed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@BartZalas This link helped a lot. Thank you.

As mentioned in GitHub this is a bug when "allow guest checkout" is not selected. We have a site where we do not want guest users to be able to buy anything without have an account.

The issue is even when logged in you have a tag in the database called "Customer_is_guest:1" so even logged in you are seen as a guest user.

In the error log as mentioned in my question i checked the QuoteAddressValidator.php:79 and it says  //Existing address cannot belong to a guest.

As i can see there is no fix for this atm, only a workaround to change "user_is_guest" from 1 to 0. But the problem will come back. If anyone has a permanently fix for this, please let me know :)